# Cached entries and postDate / expirationDate

Tags: cache, postdate

How does the `{% cache %}` tag handle a situation where an entry reaches its post date or expires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it will ignore them and will only invalidate according to any [explicit parameters](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache#parameters) you've told it to.

However, I think it should take into account an entry's post and expiration date so I've added it to our todo list.